# Passing NSManagedObject with userInfo dictionary of NSLocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm developing a time management app using Core Data. The problem is: how to pass instance of NSManagedObject via NSLocalNotification's userInfo. Packing userInfo is quite easy:

```
NSURL *uri = [[self objectID] URIRepresentation];
NSData *uriData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:uri];

NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"Name" : self.name, 
                        @"Activity" : uriData };
```

The problem is with getting object from userInfo. I use method described in [Cocoa with love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/safely-fetching-nsmanagedobject-by-uri.html). But when `didReceiveLocalNotification:`method is executed, I get the exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData relativeString]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x787c69b0'

Here is what I do in `didReceiveLocalNotification:`

```
NSURL *uri = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"Activity"];    
NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [[self.context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uri];
```

I would appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Activity object that you get from your userInfo dictionary is of class `NSData`, not `NSURL`.
Try unarchiving it before :

```
NSData *uriData = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"Activity"];
NSURL *uri = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:uriData];
NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [[self.context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uri];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked for the solution all day but completely in different direction! Thank you!!